# Likert scaled covariates and binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, likert

If my independent variables are measured with 5-point Likert scales and my dependent variable is a dummy ($0$/$1$), can I use logistic regression? How are independent variables represented in SPSS?

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on if you are willing to assume the $\ln{({\rm odds})}$ of the event is linearly associated with the 5 levels in the Likert scale, and there are a few ways to detect it:

1. Plot the $\ln{({\rm odds})}$ of event against each level of your Likert scale and examine the if there is any linear trend along the levels.
2. Fit the model using 4 binary indicators (dummies) to represent the 5-level Likert scale, and then apply contrast to test for their linearity. Try search for keywords like "testing linearity in ordinal scale" for examples.

Generally, the safer bet is to fit them as four binary indicators because it's quite rare that you'd find a nice linear trend. The disadvantage is that you will need a few more predictors and this can hurt if your sample size is low.